# Why does Imagemagick convert make the first page of output PDFs too large?

Tags: linux, imagemagick

When I run

```
convert *.jpg output.pdf
```

the output looks like this:

[image]

Why is the first page bigger then the others in the PDF? The original JPEGs were all the same size!

Comment: Oh @Lord, how we love your edits!

Answer (score 1):

A JPEG image can store a resolution (i.e. pixels per inch) in addition to its geometry (actual number of pixels).  `convert` uses the resolution when converting JPEGs to a PDF.  It's probable that the first image has a lower resolution than the others.  If they have the same size in pixels, then an image with a lower pixels per inch will be bigger.

Try running `identify -verbose file.jpg` on a couple of the images.  Look for the "Resolution:" and "Print size:" lines near the beginning of that output.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and cjm's comment pointed me in the right direction, but didn't give me a solution.  I found the solution was to specify the DPI manually with the -density option:

```
convert -density *.JPG output.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The main issue of this is different resolution of your images you want to convert to pdf file.

Use below command (like *cjm* mentions) to check the resolution of your photos.

```
identify -verbose file_name.jpg | grep "Resolution"
```

All images you want to convert to pdf file should be in the same resolution like ex: 72x72. This give you more less equal size each one of your pdf pages.

Change the resolution of your images using programs like ex: `convert` ([more info](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resample)) or `gimp` ([more info](http://registry.gimp.org/node/27599))

...then run:

```
convert *.jpg output.pdf
```